# Minimal model of a non-singular complex projective surface defined over $\overline{\mathbb Q}$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes

Suppose that $S$ is a non-singular complex projective surface that is defined over $\overline{\mathbb Q}$, namely $S\cong\text{Proj}\frac{\mathbb C[T_1,T_2,\ldots,T_n]}{(f_1,\ldots,f_n)}$ where $f_i$ has coefficients in $\overline{\mathbb Q}$ for every $i=1,\ldots,n$. If $S'$ is a minimal model of $S$, then can we conclude that also $S'$ is defined over $\overline{\mathbb Q}$? Does the blow-down preserve the field of definition (for algebraically closed fields)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think so, yes.

1) If $V_{/\overline{\mathbb{Q}}}$ be a smooth projective variety.  Then on Neron-Severi groups we have $NS(V) = NS(V_{/\mathbb{C}})$.  I believe this follows from the existence of the Picard scheme: the component group of a group scheme does not change under extension from one algebraically closed field to another.

2) Let $S_{\overline{\mathbb{Q}}}$ be a smooth, projective surface.  By Castelnuovo's Criterion, minimal models are obtained precisely by a finite sequence of contractions of $-1$-curves.  By part 1), every $(-1)$-curve in the Neron-Severi group of $S_{\mathbb{C}}$ is, up to algebraic equivalence, defined over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$, so the contractions can be done over $\mathbb{\overline{Q}}$.

**Added**: In the above there is an implicit assumption that the isomorphism class of the blowdown depends only on the Neron-Severi class of the $(-1)$-curve.  I hope that's true; at the moment, I don't quite remember.  Alternatively, the above argument certainly produces at least one $\mathbb{C}$-minimal model which is defined over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$. If the surface is irrational, minimal models are unique.  If the surface is rational, then the minimal models are all known: see e.g. [here](http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Minimal_model).  They can all be defined over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$.

Comment: Beautiful answer but I have still a doubt when you at the end write "...so the contractions can be done over $\overline{\mathbb Q}$". I formally don't see this. Why the contraction of a $(-1)$-curve defined over $\overline {\mathbb Q}$ is a morphism defined over $\overline {\mathbb Q}$?

Comment: Hartshorne, Theorem V.5.7, proves Castelnuovo's Criterion over any algebraically closed field.